# DecisionTreeClassifier model.fit(X, y) command is returning an error

Tags: python, pandas, decision-tree

I am coding a model to predict travel times based of a distance. I am getting

> ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' error when I run this code:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
times = pd.read_csv('SC.csv')
X = times.drop(columns=['Time'])
y = times.drop(columns=['distance'])

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your targets are float values, not integers. You might be trying to classify continuous targets.

Maybe try `DecisionTreeRegressor()`, or convert your targets to integers if your labels mistakenly got converted to float. Or double check you're using the right columns.